# select data from mysql and display it in order of expiry date

Tags: php, mysql

I want to be able to display ***document name*** and ***expiry date*** in order of expiry date in my browser. Mysql table name is **employee_doc** and the database name is **employee_info**. Here is my code

```
    <?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$dbname = 'employee_info';

$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

if(! $conn ) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . $mysqli->connect_error());
    }   

$mysqli = 'SELECT * FROM `employee_doc` ORDER BY `employee_doc`.`PPExp` ASC';
mysqli_connect($conn,"employee_info");
$retval = mysqli_query($conn,$mysqli);

  if(! $retval ) {
  die('Could not get data: ' . $mysqli->connect_error());
    }

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($retval, MYSQLI_ASSOC))  {
 echo $row['PPNO'];
 echo "<br>";
 echo $row['PPExp'];
 echo "<br>";
}  
mysqli_close($conn); 
?>
```

**PPExp** and **PPNO** are the column headings for ***expiry date*** and ***document name*** respectively. I am using Xampp. When I open the file from localhost  **die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());** is executed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Mixing `mysqli with mysql`

Comment: you should really change your mysql_error() to $mysqli->connect_error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **mysqli_connect:** Open a new connection to the MySQL server.
>
> **mysqli_select_db:** Selects the default database to be used when
>   performing queries against the database connection. This function
>   should only be used to change the default database for the connection.

This explains the basic concepts of both the functions. 
Check [mysqli_connect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php) and [mysqli_select_db](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php) for detailed explanation.

Change your code as follows:

```
<?php
    $dbhost = 'localhost';
    $dbuser = 'root';
    $dbpass = '';
    $dbname = 'employee_info';

    $conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

    if(! $conn ) 
    {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
    } 

    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `employee_doc` ORDER BY `employee_doc`.`PPExp` ASC';

    $retval = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

    if(! $retval ) 
    {
        die('Could not get data: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
    }

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($retval, MYSQLI_ASSOC))  
    {
        echo $row['PPNO'];
        echo "<br>";
        echo $row['PPExp'];
        echo "<br>";
    }  

    mysqli_close($conn); 
?>
```

Also you are mixing `mysql` and `mysqli`

Comment: Thank you. your code has removed all the errors. How ever I am getting the following message: "Could not get data: Unknown column 'employee_doc.PPExp' in 'order clause'". Is it to do with my code or my database (using phpmyadmin) ?

Comment: The error says that you don't have column named `PPExp` in your `employee_doc` table. So this deals with your database table...! may be missing column or some spelling error or anything else..

Comment: its COL 2 in my table. Changed it. I am getting a undefined index for all the no of entries in my table.

Comment: check your column names in database table and access using the same names in code. Or else share your table structure so that we can come to know the exact names of table columns and help you accordingly.

Comment: i made some changes and it works. Thank you very much for your prompt and timely  efforts.

Comment: This code only orders the documents based on the first digit (day ) and that also skips 2 and goes to 13 after 1. What If i want to make it linear and also consider the month and year?

Answer (score 2):

You need to include the database name in your mysql connection.

*Your code*:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
```

*Revised Code*:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, "employee_info");
```

Comment: I have edited my code and uploaded it in my question. I am getting the following errors : Warning: mysqli_connect() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\test1\Documenttest2.php on line 14 Fatal error: Call to a member function connect_error() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\test1\Documenttest2.php on line 18

Answer (score 0):

Provide database name:

$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass,$dbname);

and changes in

$retval = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

and

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($retval))

Comment: can you check my updated code in the question. I am still getting the following error : 
Warning: mysqli_connect() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\test1\Documenttest2.php on line 14

Fatal error: Call to a member function connect_error() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\test1\Documenttest2.php on line 18

Answer (score 0):

mysqli_select_db is use for changing current database to new database and using that for selecting database is not currect

You should select db in the process of  mysqli_connect as others explained.

see: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php

Comment: I have edited my code and uploaded it in my question. I am getting the following errors : 
Warning: mysqli_connect() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\test1\Documenttest2.php on line 14

Fatal error: Call to a member function connect_error() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\test1\Documenttest2.php on line 18